# how to get domain of the javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible from within a javascript file know which is the url where the script is pulled from? I mean: I have 2 servers (suppose serverA and serverB) that host the same copy of test.js (I cannot use 2 versions of test.js, it must be the same). On a 3rd part site there's a reference to https://serverA/test.js. On another 3rd part site there's a reference to https://serverB/test.js.
How can I make so the script reference to images, resources and so on of the correct server?

Comment: Clientside or Serverside? `window.location` will have information for the former.

Comment: Use `window.location.hostname`

Comment: @Gavin — That will give the URL of the HTML document not the JS

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) to get the `<script>` element and then `getAttribute('src')` to get its URL.